# Signing java application with bundled jre for mac using appbundler

Tags: java, macos, code-signing, app-bundle

I have created a java application and followed these tutorials to bundle it with a jre and convert to .app package:
https://www.jemchicomac.com/signing-a-sandbox-app-in-osx/
http://speling.shemnon.com/blog/2014/04/10/getting-your-java-app-in-the-mac-app-store/

I can create .app package successfully using their advises.
The problem is that when i try to use codesign command to sign myApp.app package, it fails with this error:
code object is not signed at all
In subcomponent: Path to MyApp.app/Contents/PlugIns/jre/Contents/Home/jre/lib/calendars.properties

I deleted calendars.properties for testing, but the error occurred again for another file.The only way i have found is to remove whole jre folder form package and codesign works correctly. then i sign jre executable files separately and copy jre folder to Plugins folder of myApp.app again.
Can anybody tell me what is the problem? and how can i do signing using methods offered in links above?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

After a long investigation I found out from talking to an Apple engineer that the "jre" subfolder needs to have a file extension in order for codesign to behave properly.  In my case changing the path from Contents/PlugIns/jre to Contents/PlugIns/jre.bundle solved the problem.  Maybe codesign has been fixed since then, but if not I hope this is helpful.